# Delete From All Tables in SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Is there a SQL command in SQLite (for C#.NET) which performs the equivalent of this?

`DELETE * FROM * WHERE id='idnumber'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sqlite: How do I reset all database tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600075/sqlite-how-do-i-reset-all-database-tables)

Comment: @juergend This question is about deleting a single record from all tables rather than all records from all tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's not.

One way is to write a little script to [query metadata tables](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) to *create* another script with a series of individual `delete` statements, one per table.

An example could be (assuming *every* table had an ID column):

```
select 'delete from ' || name || ' where ID = 42'
from sqlite_master
where type = 'table'
```

This would generate a `delete` statement for each table which you could then capture and run as a script.

But it's generally a good idea for database developers to know the names of their tables :-)

Answer (score 0):

This remove will wipe all content from your database:

```
.output wipe.sql
.print BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' || name || ' WHERE id="idnumber";'
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table';
.print COMMIT;
.print VACUUM;
.output
-- .read wipe.sql
```

Beware that if you leave out the `WHERE id="idnumber"` this will wipe your database!

Answer (score 0):

A method that I use for dynamic programmatic purposes is creating an array of the table names and loop through them.

e.g.

Swift

```
var array = ['table1','table2','table3']

for item in array

{
    
var stringToDeleteTables:String = "DELETE FROM \\(item) [optional where clause]"

//run the command on the database

}
```

I hope this helps someone. Great for things such as sign outs or clearing search data. You can even make an extension of an array and call it as a function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use try it :

```
//You can do it with the following DANGEROUS commands:

PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
delete from sqlite_master where type = 'table';
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;



 //you then want to recover the deleted space with
 VACUUM

//and a good test to make sure everything is ok
 PRAGMA INTEGRITY_CHECK;
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: That's going to delete the tables, yes? I think the OP just wants to delete all rows with a matching ID from all tables. So probably not _that_ useful :-)