# reset a database before each test

Tags: node.js, supertest

I'm using node and supertest for a simple app. I got SQlite3 for the local test database. I did a simple test to get a super inserted into the database. I wanted to reset the database each time a test is run. I'm looking in the docs right now and can't seem to locate it. I figured I would ask here because it seems someone would most likely know the info.

```
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('../server');

describe('Authentication', function() {

//database reset here

  it('should create a new user /users/registration', function(done) {
    request(server)
      .post('/users/register')
      .send({
        username: 'user-name',
        email: 'luser-name@gmail.com',
        password: '12345'
      })
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(201, done);
  });
});
```

Comment: The proper way to do this would probably to create a mock endpoint that doesn't actually read your db or insert it simply returns fixed data for selects and true for inserts

Comment: are you using jest?

Comment: yes I am using jest

Comment: Depending on what level you're trying to test at, mocking may or may not be the right approach. If you're testing the functionality of your APIs, mocking is the way to go; if you're testing the integration between your APIs and a database, then the OP's approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run any piece of code before each test, you can use [beforeEach](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown) function in `jest`

```
describe('my test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
       // code to run before each test
    });

    test('test 1', () => {
      // code
    });

   test('test 2', () => {
      // code
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So best way to do this is have some logic in your routing functions of your Api

```
Receive an API request
Check if ['X-MOCK-HEADER'] exists
If it does then route to the mock version of the endpoint
```

So your mock for create user would always return 201 OK - your mock endpoint would do something like this:

```
const routes = {
   CREATE_USER_OK:() => { return {....} } // make sure these return proper http responses
   CREATE_USER_BAD_REQUEST: () { return {...} }
}

 return routes[HEADER_VALUE]()
```

The reason being you're testing the route not the database class in this instance, so you just want to return static data, if you wanna test something else then just change the X-MOCK-HEADER value to whatever you want and add the mock route to return the right http response/code - I'd need to know what the API code looked like to help you on the backend implementation.

If possible stay away from messing with staging databases for testing because down the road you will suffer a LOT of pain as it gradually gets filled with garbage.

Also if you're working with a front end app you can quickly prototype with static data - this is especially useful if you've got a front end team waiting for an API endpoint to say create a login screen.

Answer (score 0):

There's no defined way to reset a sqlite db, just delete the db and recreate.

[Sqlite: How do I reset all database tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600075/sqlite-how-do-i-reset-all-database-tables)

Comment: Yeah but if you do this then you have code to delete a database that will run in production, so if someone broke it down the line your tests could wipe your prod database.

Comment: Sorry run in prod and check and env var to see if it's staging or prod, so if check broke it could in theory wipe a prod db!

Comment: but if the env var is set to prod ,then check shouldn't break

Comment: @Mrk Fldig You wouldn't run tests in production. You would deploy after testing right?

Comment: Yes but your env vars before deploying to prod would be prod urls usually

Comment: You are right in terms clearing the table data though - it'd give me sweats at night knowing that an entire table deletion/wipe is prevented by if(process.env....)

Comment: You can create a new empty db and use

Comment: don't touch the prod db

Comment: Yeah I mean if that's the way you're happy with it, it largely depends on your project and team size etc! Me personally it'd scare the pants off me.

Comment: you want to reset the db before each test, so space-wise having an empty db wouldn't have any impact

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the file and it works fine

```
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('../server');
const knex = require('knex');
const dbConfig = require('../knexfile.js')['test'];
const db = knex(dbConfig);

describe('Authentication', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await db('users').truncate();
  });

  it('should create a new user /users/registration', function(done) {
    request(server)
      .post('/users/register')
      .send({
        username: 'user-name',
        email: 'luser-name@gmail.com',
        password: '12345'
      })
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(201, done);
  });
});
```